# Random GPU frequency clock spikes cause FPS drops / lag / stuttering

Tags: windows-10, gpu, lag, clockspeed

after testing some games (PUBG, Rocket League, GTA V, Rust, Total War Warhammer, Ark) I noticed that I get random GPU frequency core spikes from 1920Mhz to 1520Mhz, this result in stuttering and lag. All drivers are updated, temps are fine, CPU and GPU never go above 60C, games were tested on SSD (primary disk) and on the secondy drive (HDD), all Nvida control panel settings are stock, I also tried different combination from what I've found on the internet but I'm not able to fix this.

Full system specs:
-i5-6600k (no OC, turbo mode enabled as default)
- MSI GTX 1060 6GB GAMING
- ASUS MAXIMUS RANGER VIII
- G.Skill Ripjaws V 3200 DDR4
- Samsung 850 EVO
- WD Caviar Blue 1TB

Comment: Do you have MSI After Burner installed? Use that to "lock" the GPU's frequency to whatever you choose (probably the 1920Mhz), and see if the stuttering is impacted at all.  This will at least tell you if this is really the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're overclocked, make sure that you prioritize your temperatures as there is more headroom with temps rather than power limit. I find my 1080s clock speeds stay constant after doing that. MSI afterburner took out this feature but EVGA precision XOC still has it. Might wanna try it out.
Source:
[**YouTube**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VeQe6pEEtVI)